# Is $\varliminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty} |n \sin n| = 0$ correct, where $n$ is an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, open-problems, limits-and-convergence

Is it true that $\varliminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty} |n \sin n| = 0$, where $n$
runs over the integers?

The existence of the limes inferior follows from [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem),
but the problem is to prove that it is $0$.

Comment: That's equivalent to asking whether $n\pi$ comes within $o(1/n)$ of an integer,
which is a well-known open problem; it's expected to be true
(if $\pi$ is replaced by a random number then it's true with probability $1$)
but well beyond what can be proved by known methods. (The Dirichlet result you quote gives $O(1/n)$ in place of the desired $o(1/n)$.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a well-known open question. 

Comment: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/dense_sine

Comment: This question was closed because it asks about a well-known open question. Why has it been reopened? Has someone solved it?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221018/is-n-sin-n-dense-on-the-real-line

Answer (score 7):

This is an open question. See the comments for more details.

Comment: Just a technical answer (community wiki) so that this question can be considered answered and so that exact duplicates can be linked it.