# Is liminf|(n*sinn)|=0 as n tends to infinity?

Tags: nt.number-theory

One of my friends asked me that is $\varliminf |nsinn|=0$?
I think maybe it has some relations with Number theory, But I don't know how to solve it. If you know the answer, please tell me since it really puzzles me！

Comment: You might like to look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1 .

Comment: This question has been asked here before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144080/is-varliminf-n-rightarrow-infty-n-sin-n-0-correct-where-n-is-an